# Background tasks Optimize use of resources

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, scheduled-tasks

My question is around execution of tasks and optimizing resources. I have a set of tasks that I pick up by polling a database. Most of these tasks do these operation :

1. Connect to another server (SQL, MDX, Webservice etc.) and query data. (Not I/O intensive)
2. Receive the data and save to an file on a folder in the server (I/O work)

Currently I am approaching by creating a queue of task metadata. Task metadata is picked up and a Task is created (so that it runs of separate thread) and executed. I have now limited the number of concurrent task to number of processor cores available.

Obviously I am looking at maximizing the server resources so that I process most tasks as soon as possible. What I was looking was if there is a chance for improvement.

Here is how I look at it. if you look at my fist operation step, it is not a I/O intensive work, but just a call to a separate server, but these calls can be long running. The second step is an I/O work (but that is not too intensive) as it just saves the data.

For example lets say, I have 2 processor cores and 4 pending task to complete (Task1, Task2, Task3, Task4). Task1 and Task2 will be picked up and a thread (Lets say Thread1, Thread2) are working on Taks1 and Task2 respectively. The threads Thread1 and Thread2 are blocked in my case till it finishes (with data retrieval and Saving file). Once they complete they pick up Task3 and Task4.

What I was thinking (just a theory right now) if I can make the first step of the operation call as Async on a separate thread so that these threads do not wait for the entire steps to complete. For example, Thread1, Thread2 can spin up a separate threads (Lets say Thread1A,Thread2A) to do the call to servers for data respectively and when complete returns back to Thread1 and Thread2. Then the thread Thread1 and Thread2 (when free) receives the data and writes it to the file. What it does is that in the mean time Thread1 and Thread2 can also work on Task3 and Task4.

Would this be a feasible approach. Or is there any better approach to this. Also would want to know what are the maximum threads that I can create for these types of operations :

1. Calls to database server/service.
2. I/O operations (create file, write file etc.)

Please suggest. Any pointers/sample code or links would help.

Regards,
Girija Shankar

Comment: Sounds like a job for _[I/O Completion Ports (IOCP)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)_.  Up! up! and away!  IOCP out-scales standard overlapped I/O.  IOCP can service a great deal of requests using a small number of thread-pool threads

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me, if it's just connecting to a server I don't see why you don't just put that code in the same thread as the one that writes the data to be honest. I think it would also be safe to have more connection threads than the number of processor cores since they aren't doing anything intensive.

Comment: @Logan:  Thanks for the reply. I did not get the line where you say "I don't see why you don't just put that code in the same thread as the one that writes the data to be honest". If I understood correctly what you are referring is that, Why I am not putting the call code in the Thread1 and Thread 2. I currently have the same thing. This is what each thread does : 1. Connect to server fire the query and wait. 2. Once Query execution data is received write to file. But the problem is it is synchronous. Can I do this asynchronous ? If so, What is the max threads that I can open like this ?